# Instance of 'OneToOneField' has no 'username' member django 2.2.5

Tags: python, django, django-models

I got the following error when I created Profile model:

> Instance of 'OneToOneField' has no 'username' member

This is the snippet of the code I created:

```
class Profile (models.Model):
        #Proxy model que hereda los datos base 

    #Primer argumento onetoone on delete define lo que pasa cunado se
    #elimina el registro que este relaciondo
        user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        website=models.URLField(max_length=100,blank=True)
        biography=models.TextField(blank=True)
        phone_number=models.CharField(max_length=8)
        #Django guarda la referencia al archivo
        profile_picture= models.ImageField(
            upload_to='users/pictures',
            blank=True,
            null=True
        )
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        modified=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)



        def __str__ (self):
            return self.user.username
```

I’m getting the error in:

```
return self.user.username
```

Comment: AFAIK we use `ForeignKey` for such cases not `OneToOneField`

Comment: Does the `User` model have a `username` field?  The standard django `User` model does, but perhaps you're using a custom `User` model?

Comment: I am using django´s

Comment: When you create a `Profile` object, how are you specifying the `User` relation?  Can you show us the code that creates new `Profile` objects?

Comment: That is not an error. It is a warning from your IDE. You should ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the error you are getting or at least similar to the error you are getting? [image]

It is just the IDE not seeing the field in `user`.  If you are using the default `User` model, it should be fine. I use `self.user.username` frequently and that error is everywhere I have it.